# What seem to be an error in Java and Sqlite database communication?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I been working in the android application and performing search to sqlite database from what user entered into the `edittext` box. I have other functions are working fine, as soon as I pressed "find" the app crashes. The search performing code is the very last function  `public void find(View v)`.

```
package au.edu.rmit.contact;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
SQLiteDatabase db;
TextView tv;
EditText et1,et2,et3,query;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //initialize all view objects
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    et2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    et3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

    //create database if not already exist
    db= openOrCreateDatabase("Mydb2", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    //create new table if not already exist
    db.execSQL("create table if not exists roster1(name varchar, sur_name  varchar, time varchar)");
}
//This method will call on when we click on insert button
public void insert(View v)
{
    String name=et1.getText().toString();
    String sur_name=et2.getText().toString();
    String time=et3.getText().toString();
    et1.setText("");
    et2.setText("");
    et3.setText("");
    //insert data into able
    db.execSQL("insert into roster1 values('"+name+"','"+sur_name+"','"+time+"')");
    //display Toast
    Toast.makeText(this, "values inserted successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
//This method will call when we click on display button
public void display(View v)
{
    //use cursor to keep all data
    //cursor can keep data of any data type
    Cursor c=db.rawQuery("select * from roster1", null);
    tv.setText("");
    //move cursor to first position
    c.moveToFirst();
    //fetch all data one by one
    do
    {
        //we can use c.getString(0) here
        //or we can get data using column index
        String name=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
        String surname=c.getString(1);
        String time=c.getString(2);

        //display on text view
        tv.append("Name:"+name+" , Roles:"+surname+", Time:"+time+"\n");
        //move next position until end of the data
    }while(c.moveToNext());
}
 //------------------Search------------------------//
public void find(View v)
{
    query=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);

    String search=query.getText().toString();
    query.setText("");

    //use cursor to keep all data
    //cursor can keep data of any data type

    Cursor c=db.rawQuery("select * from roster1 where Name = ?",new String[] {"%" + search + "%"});


    tv.setText("");
    //move cursor to first position
    c.moveToFirst();
    //fetch all data one by one
    do
    {
        //we can use c.getString(0) here
        //or we can get data using column index
        String name=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
        String surname=c.getString(1);
        String time=c.getString(2);

        //display on text view
        tv.append("Name:"+name+" , Roles:"+surname+", Time:"+time+"\n");
        //move next position until end of the data
    }while(c.moveToNext());
}



}
```

LogCat
[image]
Thank you

Comment: Can you post logcat of crash here

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to find query textview in your java.
Thats why it gives null pointer exception.

Use this

```
query =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.query_editText);
```

Comment: replace query_edittext with id of query textview in your app.

Comment: according to exception its CursorIndexOutOfBound

Answer (score 0):

You did not use the `c.moveToFirst();` properly. The main purpose of this is to know whether our cursor has a value, therefore if it has no value; you should not execute any loops like your `do-while-loop`.

```
if(c.moveToFirst()){
  do{
    //code here
  }while(c.moveToNext());
}
```

If you read the Error it says `CursorIndexOutOfBound with a size of Zero` which means that your trying to get a value from the cursor with zero items.